# Is it possible to have a grouping grid with another grid inside of the expansion?

Tags: java, gwt, gxt

Is it possible to have a grouping grid with another grid inside of the expansion?

I'm wondering if it's possible to have a grouping grid and on expansion of a category have another grid? What I need is to have a different set of column headers for each group but I'm not entirely sure that it's possible and if so I'd appreciate how to get started on it or a nudge in the right direction.

Comment: I am not sure I understand your need. I think that a TreeGrid would meet your need.